# Mark all rows that meet two conditions and has the lowest value on a third

Tags: sql-server

I need to mark all the first occurences (lowest ID in table_a) where two conditions (customer and user) match the conditions in another table (customer and user in table_b). A very simplified version of the problem is here:

table_a

```
 Id          Customer        Users         
-----        --------        ----
 100           1001           abc
 101           1001           abc
 102           1001           xyz
 103           1001           xyz
 104           1002           abc
 105           1002           abc
 106           1002           xyz
 107           1002           xyz
```

table_b

```
Customer   Users    
--------   -----
  1001      abc
  1002      xyz
```

What I want:

```
 Id          Customer        User     include         
-----        --------        ----     -------
 100           1001           abc        1
 101           1001           abc        0
 102           1001           xyz        0
 103           1001           xyz        0
 104           1002           abc        0
 105           1002           abc        0
 106           1002           xyz        1  
 107           1002           xyz        0
```

this what I tried:

```
select a.*, case when exists(
    select 1
    from table_a a1, table_b b
    where a.customer=b.customer
    and a.user=b.user
    having min(a1.id)=a.id
    )
then 1 else 0 end as include
```

but only the first row (lowest ID) in the whole list is marked. If the conditions are not met in the first row (user and customer combo don´t match the one on table_b) none is marked.

There is some logic I miss here. Any suggestion? The real table_a has million of rows so speed is a concern. So besides logic I probably also need some speed magic.

The full code is here:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table_a
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table_b

create table #table_a (Id char(3),Customer char(4),Users char(3))
insert into #table_a (Id,Customer,Users) values

('100','1001','abc'),
('101','1001','abc'),
('102','1001','xyz'),
('103','1001','xyz'),
('104','1002','abc'),
('105','1002','abc'),
('106','1002','xyz'),
('107','1002','xyz')

create table #table_b (Customer char(4),Users char(3))
insert into #table_b (Customer,Users) values
('1001','abc'),
('1002','xyz')

    select a.*
    , case when exists(
        select *
        from #table_a a1, #table_b b
        where a.customer=b.customer
        and a.users=b.users
        having min(a1.id)=a.id
        )

    then 1 else 0 end as include
    from #table_a a
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick, if you can use windowed functions in your version of SQL Server:

```
WITH Includes AS (
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        CASE WHEN b.Customer IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [include],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Customer, a.Users ORDER BY a.Id) AS include_id
    FROM 
        #table_a a
        LEFT JOIN #table_b b ON b.Customer = a.Customer AND b.Users = a.Users)
SELECT
    a.*,
    CASE WHEN i.include_id = 1 THEN i.[include] ELSE 0 END AS [include]
FROM
    #table_a a
    LEFT JOIN Includes i ON i.Id = a.Id;
```

Basically it builds up a list of matches, then uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to pick the first one from each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following query:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Customer, a.Users, 
       CASE 
          WHEN SUM(IIF(b.Customer IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY a.Customer ORDER BY a.Id) = 1 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS include 
FROM #table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN #table_b AS b ON a.Customer = b.Customer AND a.Users = b.Users
```

The query assumes that there is *at most* one match between `#table_a` and `#table_b`.

**Explanation:**

The query uses `SUM() OVER()` with an `ORDER BY` clause in order to caculate the running total of records having a match. So, this query:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Customer, a.Users, 
       SUM(IIF(b.Customer IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY a.Customer ORDER BY a.Id) AS cnt
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON a.Customer = b.Customer AND a.Users = b.Users
```

produces this output:

```
Id  Customer  Users cnt
-----------------------
100 1001      abc   1
101 1001      abc   2
102 1001      xyz   2
103 1001      xyz   2
104 1002      abc   0
105 1002      abc   0
106 1002      xyz   1
107 1002      xyz   2
```

The record having `cnt=1` is the one we are looking for.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94d29/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, 
CASE WHEN a.Id = a1.Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [include]
FROM #table_a a
    LEFT JOIN #table_b b ON a.Customer = b.Customer
        AND a.Users = b.Users
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 Id
        FROM #table_a a
        WHERE  a.Customer = b.Customer
            AND a.Users = b.Users
        ) a1
```